# How to extract the keywords and search it in the database records in SQL?

Tags: sql

So I have a table like below

```
+------+-----------------+
| Bil. | ID    | Product |
+------+-----------------+
| 1    | EX001 | OneO    |
| 2    | EX002 | TwoT    |
| 3    | EX003 | ThreeT  |
+------+-----------------+
```

I am typing 3 keywords with comma **EX001,EX002,EX003** in the editor and I don't know how to extract this keywords to find the records in the database. Is there anyway to extract this keywords?

Comment: Can you bit more specific? Like, what database and editor are you talking about? What have you tried? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` -- if you must:

```
select t.*
from t
where concat(',', ?, ',') like concat('%,', id, ',%');
```

However, the more common approach would be to transform the query to:

```
where id in ('EX001', 'EX002', 'EX003')
```

How you do this depends on your database and your application.